# VueX state one step behind with dynamic routes (nuxt)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I am trying to update my state every route change by updating the 'activeCategory' of a post.

I am firing a VueX action every time the route changes. But the state is always one step behind, as it displays the category for the previous post not the current one.

I fire the action on mounted when the user initially hits the page and then fire the action every route change as i'm using dynamic routes.

Any help would be great!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved this 5 minutes after posting the question. I simply put the action into the "updated" lifecycle which would fire my action every time the page is updated.